# Suppressing the use of an XML attribute inherited from a base schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

I'd like to suppress the use of an attribute (underline) inherited from a base schema (BaseSchema.xsd) without redefining the entire element TextType, if possible, in the manner demonstrated in the following example:

Base schema (BaseSchema.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Text" type="TextType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TextType"> <!-- Actual example is much longer -->
        <xs:attribute name="bold" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:attribute name="italics" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:attribute name="underline" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Derived schema (DerivedSchema.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:override schemaLocation="BaseSchema.xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="TextType">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="TextType">
                    <xs:attribute name="underline" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/>                  
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:override>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem here is that `TextType` in `<xs:extension base="TextType">` amounts to a circular definition, and I'd like to identify it as the `TextType` defined in the base schema.

**Solution, based on xs:redefine** thanks to Michael

Base schema (edited)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Text" type="TextType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TextType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="bold" type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:attribute name="italics" type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:attribute name="underline" type="xs:boolean"/>                
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Derived schema (edited)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="BaseSchema.xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="TextType">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:restriction base="TextType">
                    <xs:attribute name="underline" type="xs:boolean" use="prohibited"/> 
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xs:override (unlike xs:redefine) doesn't allow you to define the new type by derivation from the old type, rather you define a replacement for the original type "from scratch". If you want to reduce the amount of stuff that's unnecessarily replicated in the new definition, use smaller-granularity components, e.g. define each of the attributes as a global attribute group, so you only need to override one of them. (But I have a feeling that defining an attribute as prohibited within an attribute group is ineffective, so that might not work.)

Comment: `xs:redefine` works beautifully in Saxon and Xerces2-j. Unfortunately it is deprecated so I'm not quite sure what to do. Placing underline by itself in an attribute group also works but its ugly.

Comment: I shouldn't worry too much about things that are deprecated if they work for you. The main reason it's deprecated is that the WG gave up the struggle of defining the semantics in such a way that all implementations would be interoperable for all corner cases.

Comment: Do deprecated, in this case, does not mean validators will no longer support it? More importantly, will Saxon continue to support `xs:redefine`?

Comment: Any product that wants to be widely used in the field is going to support xs:redefine (as best it can) until people stop using it.